# MYSQL queries, set theory and greater than

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have a database that has 2 tables one for awards and one for movies. 
Table movies has the rating and (PK) movie title:

```
 |  title      |  rating
 |  Avatar     |   5.0
 |  mid summer |   7.0
 |  terminator |   8.0
```

Table awards has movie title (FK), award, result (won or nominated):

```
   |title        |  award |  result     |
   |avatar       |  oscar |   won       |
   |mid summer   |  oscar |   nominated |
   |terminator   |  bafta |   nominated |
```

The query i am trying to execute is to find all pairs of movies (m1, m2 ) nominated for the same award, such that m1 has
higher rating than m2 , but m2 won the award.
The result should return:

```
 |avatar    | oscar |won       | 5.0
 |midsummer | oscar |nominated | 7.0
```

I have tried inner join but each time it will only show distinct values. Alterations have returned the wrong result.
example of code i have tried:

```
 select a.award as 'Award', a.result as 'Result', m.rating as 'Average 
 rating',  m.title as 'Movie'  from awards as a
 inner join movies as m 
 on a.title = m.title
 where a.result ='won' or a.result = 'nominated'
 group by a.award;
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization. When you get a result that you don't expect, find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first erroneous subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: We still can't cut & paste & run, etc, etc, per my last comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must join `movies` to `awards` twice:

```
select m1.title, a1.award, a1.result, m1.rating
from movies m1 
inner join awards a1 on a1.title = m1.title 
inner join awards a2 on a2.award = a1.award and a2.result <> a1.result
inner join movies m2 on m2.title = a2.title
where case a1.result when 'won' then m1.rating else m2.rating end <
      case a1.result when 'won' then m2.rating else m1.rating end
```

You should add an `ORDER BY` clause like:

```
order by 
  case a1.result when 'won' then a1.title else a2.title end,
  least(m1.rating, m2.rating),
  greatest(m1.rating, m2.rating)
```

because there would be multiple pairs of rows returned.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=1bd9df61a67cfb9eb491f09439ab9cc3).
Results:

```
> title      | award | result    | rating
> :--------- | :---- | :-------- | -----:
> Avatar     | oscar | won       |      5
> mid summer | oscar | nominated |      7
```

Comment: Hi, thank you this worked. I had worked my way towards the query of your first example. This helped a lot :)